# Safe guard API token for Jenkins Plugins

Tags: jenkins, token, jenkins-job-dsl, flowdock

I am using [Flowdock plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flowdock+Plugin) in Jenkins. For this I need to give API token. right now I am hard coding my Flowdock API token as follow:

```
publishers {
   flowdock(FLOWDOCK_TOKEN) {
      failure()
      tags('tag1', 'tag2')
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having this hard coded token in the code? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Job DSL wiki has a section about [Handling Credentials](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Handling-Credentials#build-variables), that mentions the Flowdock plugin in an example.